# Test in SciPy returns NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Test in SciPy returns NAN. kindly help

`alive = covid_df[covid_df['new_death'] == 1]`
`dead = covid_df[covid_df['new_death'] == 0]`
`mean = covid_df.groupby('new_death').agg({'age':['mean']})`
`print(mean)`
age
mean
new_death
0          48.072293
1          68.586207

`import scipy.stats as stats`

My code:
`stats.ttest_ind(alive.age,dead.age)`

Result:
`Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was doing a 2 sample  T test in scipy and was getting this result Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)